# After breaking my GRUB installation, wiping the drive and reinstalling, Xubuntu launches but there is no GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

To be specific in that mess of a title, I broke my last Xubuntu install (writing to askubuntu as the two are very similar) so I wiped the drive in Gparted. I then installed Xubuntu with the something else option, added 8gb swap and the / mount. I selected SDB for GRUB to be installed on. Here are my drives:

SDA: 2tb hard drive that I use for Windows data (games, data).
SDB: My Linux SSD. Completely wiped for this installation.
SDC: Windows SSD.

My issue is that the OS doesn't show up in my BIOS boot and the GRUB menu doesn't show; to access my Xubuntu installation, I have to manually select the drive (Kingston:*drive model*) from the boot menu. After looking in SDB with Gparted (after the install), I noticed that there was no EFI; just the swap and the / .

Note: I intend to dual boot Windows and Xubuntu.

Is it possible to "install GRUB"? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out GRUB was written on my Windows drive and also messed up the Windows bootloader. Note for next time: unplug all your drives apart from the one you are installing on haha